# Salesforce Authenticator - We received an unrecognized request

Tags: authentication, login, login-errors, two-factor-authentication

Has anyone seen this error before with the Salesforce Authenticator app?

> We received an unrecognized request
>   We found a request for a previous installation of the app.  We took care of it for you, so you can continue using  Salesforce Authenticator

I’m unable to log into my dev instance with two-factor authentication. Upon entering my username and password, the app pushes a notification to my phone but doesn’t show the **Approve** or **Deny** options. The 6-digit code doesn’t work either when I try that option.

[image: We received an unrecognized request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up logging a ticket with [Trailhead support](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help) and they disconnected my 2 factor authentication so that I could reconnect. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I have a user who is suffering this now. It works once and then not at all. I remove the connection from his account, he connects, it works once... ad infinitum